# How to avoid java.util.NoSuchElementException

Tags: java.util.scanner

The code below is giving me the error java.util.NoSuchElementException right after I Ctrl+Z
to indicate that the user input is complete. By the looks of it seems as if it does not know how to just end one method without messing with the other scanner object.
I try the hasNext method and I ended up with an infinite loop, either way is not working. As a requirement for this assignment I need to be able to tell the user to use Ctrl+Z or D depending on the operating system. Also I need to be able to read from a text file and save the final tree to a text file please help.

```
    /* sample input:
       CSCI3320
       project
       personal
       1 HW1
       1 HW2
       1 2 MSS.java
       2 p1.java

        */

    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.util.StringTokenizer;

    public class Directory {

        private static TreeNode root = new TreeNode("/", null, null);

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            userMenu();
            System.out.println("The directory is displayed as follows:");
            root.listAll(0);

        }

        private static void userMenu(){         //Displays users menu
            Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);//Scanner option 
            int option = 0;
            do{ //I believe the problem is here since I am not using userInput.Next()
                System.out.println("\n 1. add files from user inputs ");
                System.out.println("\n 2. display the whole directory ");
                System.out.println("\n 3. display the size of directory ");
                System.out.println("\n 0. exit");
                System.out.println("\n Please give a selection [0-3]: ");
                option = userInput.nextInt();
                    switch(option){
                        case 1: addFileFromUser();
                                break;
                        case 2: System.out.println("The directory is displayed as follows:");
                                root.listAll(0);
                                break;
                        case 3: System.out.printf("The size of the directory is %d.\n", root.size());
                                break;
                        default:
                                break;
                        }
            }while( option !=0);
            userInput.close();

        }
        private static void addFileFromUser() {

            System.out.println("To terminate inp1ut, type the correct end-of-file indicator ");
            System.out.println("when you are prompted to enter input.");
            System.out.println("On UNIX/Linux/Mac OS X type <ctrl> d");
            System.out.println("On Windows type <ctrl> z");
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

                while (input.hasNext()) { //hasNext being used Crtl Z is required to break
                    addFileIntoDirectory(input); // out of the loop.
                }
                input.close();
        }


        private static void addFileIntoDirectory(Scanner input) {

            String line = input.nextLine();
            if (line.trim().equals("")) return;

            StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(line);

            int n = tokens.countTokens() - 1;

            TreeNode p = root;
            while (n > 0 && p.isDirectory()) {

                int a = Integer.valueOf( tokens.nextToken() );
                p = p.getFirstChild();

                while (a > 1 && p != null) {
                    p = p.getNextSibling();
                    a--;
                }
                n--;
            }

            String name = tokens.nextToken();

            TreeNode newNode = new TreeNode(name, null, null);
            if (p.getFirstChild() == null) {
                p.setFirstChild(newNode);
            }
            else {
                p = p.getFirstChild();
                while (p.getNextSibling() != null) {
                    p = p.getNextSibling();
                }
                p.setNextSibling(newNode);
            }

        }


        private static class TreeNode {

            private String element;
            private TreeNode firstChild;
            private TreeNode nextSibling;

            public TreeNode(String e, TreeNode f, TreeNode s) {
                setElement(e);
                setFirstChild(f);
                setNextSibling(s);
            }


            public void listAll(int i) {

                for (int k = 0; k < i; k++) {
                    System.out.print('\t');
                }

                System.out.println(getElement());

                if (isDirectory()) {
                    TreeNode t = getFirstChild();

                    while (t != null) {

                        t.listAll(i+1);
                        t = t.getNextSibling();
                    }

                }
            }


            public int size() {

                int s = 1;

                if (isDirectory()) {
                    TreeNode t = getFirstChild();

                    while (t != null) {
                        s += t.size();
                        t = t.getNextSibling();
                    }
                }

                return s;
            }


            public void setElement(String e) {
                element = e;
            }


            public String getElement() {
                return element;
            }


            public boolean isDirectory() {
                return getFirstChild() != null;
            }

            public void setFirstChild(TreeNode f) {
                firstChild = f;
            }       

            public TreeNode getFirstChild() {
                return firstChild;
            }

            public void setNextSibling(TreeNode s) {
                nextSibling = s;
            }       

            public TreeNode getNextSibling() {
                return nextSibling;
            }


        }



    }
```

Exception Details:

```
    /*Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
            at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:907)
            at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1530)
            at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2160)
            at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2119)
            at Directory.userMenu(Directory.java:36)
            at Directory.main(Directory.java:21)*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is this line:

```
option = userInput.nextInt();  //line 24
```

If you read the Javadoc, you will find that the `nextInt()` method can throw a `NoSuchElementException` if the input is exhausted. In other words, there is no next integer to get. Why is this happening in your code? Because you this line is in a loop once that first iteration completes (on the outer `while` loop) your initial input selection has been consumed. Since this is a homework, I am not going to write the code. But, if you remove the loop, you know this works at least once.  Once you try to loop, it breaks. So I will give you these hints:

1. Change the do/while to a while loop.
2. Prompt the user once outside the loop.
3. Recreate the prompt and recapture the user input inside the loop.

For example, the code below can be used for the basis of your outer loop.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GuessNumberGame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Guess the secret number: (Hint: the secret number is 1)");
        int guess = input.nextInt();

        while (guess != 1) {
            System.out.println("Wrong guess. Try again: ");
            guess = input.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.println("Success");
        input.close();
    }
}
```

The reason why this works is because I don't reuse the same, exhausted, scanner input object to get the next integer. In your example, the initial input is inside the loop. The second time around, that input has already been consumed. Follow this pattern and you should be able to complete your assignment.